# Mowing the lawn problem solving question

Tags: problem-solving

Andrew can mow the lawn in 30 minutes and Nicholas can mow the same section of lawn in 45 minutes. Working together, in how many minutes could they mow the lawn? I know the answer is 18 minutes but I don't know how the answer was solved. HELP ASAP, please!!!

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange! You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the area of the lawn section $A$. Then Andrew can mow $A/30$ per minute, while Nicholas is able to mow $A/45$ per minute. Together, they therefore would mow $$ \frac{A}{30} + \frac{A}{45} = A \frac{30 + 45}{30 \cdot 45} = \frac{A}{18}$$ per minute. This straightforwardly means that they can finish the whole section in 18 minutes.